# Magento increasing URL rewrites constantly

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, magento-1.7

I have a Magento 1.7.0.2 installation and noticed the URL rewrites have been increasing recently.

For example:
Request path: product-27x27-4804.html
Target path : product-27x27-4805.html

All the new rewrites are custom ones and what I've noticed the count increases upon reindex.

These new rewrites are not valid and are basically junk I need to clean safely but at the same time make them stop from appearing again.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this:

1. cleaning up the large URL rewrite table which will slow down your reindexes.

PLEASE BACKUP FIRST!

```
DELETE FROM core_url_rewrite WHERE category_id IS NOT NULL AND product_id IS NOT NULL;
```

2. patching magento to prevent the issue from occurring again.  See link below for this, but DON'T follow the part that suggests you should truncate the whole core_url_rewrite table.  That will remove all of your custom URL rewrites as well as the system.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17553/magento-core-url-rewrite-table-excessively-large